# 'ParameterMode cannot be resolved to a variable' when implementing stored procedure from MySQL in Spring REST api

Tags: java, mysql, rest, spring-mvc, stored-procedures

Trying to call a stored procedure in MySQL from Spring JPA in a REST api application but there is an error at ParameterMode.IN

I tried to implement @NamedStoredProcedureQuery and ended up having a syntax error at ParameterMode.IN. Below is my code.

```
@Entity
@NamedStoredProcedureQueries({
  @NamedStoredProcedureQuery(
    name = "findByUpcomingTime", 
    procedureName = "findByUpcomingTime",
    resultClasses = {ShuttleBus.class},
    parameters = { 
        @StoredProcedureParameter(
                mode = ParameterMode.IN,
                type = String.class,
                name = "in_source"),
        @StoredProcedureParameter(
                mode = ParameterMode.IN,
                type = String.class,
                name = "dest_source")}) 
})
```

It says 'ParameterMode cannot be resolved to a varilable'

Comment: Did you import `ParameterMode` ?

Comment: Thanks!! It's that simple! However, may I know why the IDE is not prompting me to import this time? Normally it should.